# Find and Load microsoft.net compact framework 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5

I have an older application on a computer that blew up and needed to have the operating system rebuilt. The application requires microsoft.net compact framework 3.5. Apparently 3.5 is no longer supported/available. Has anyone else run into and solved this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK so after much investigating and lots of dead ends, including a call to microsoft i found something that seems to have worked. I have another machine (call it machine A) with compact framework 3.5 running on it. I looked in the registry and was able to find the entry for the .netcompact framework. That pointed me to the location where the software was loaded. I copied by the registry entry and software and moved over to the machine (B) where i needed to install 3.5. I then backed up both the registry and renamed the directory with the same name as the directory I took off of machine A. I then imported the registry file and installed the directory. Finally i rebooted. So far the machine (B) seems solid and the legacy software installed is working. We'll see if i caused some harm down the road, but for now my problem seems solved.

Comment: Nice that your problem was solved! But it would be nice if you could add more specific information to your question about which error message or unwanted behavior you were seeing, and information about which application you were using. Is this software you have made yourself? Is this commercial software?